# How to add a actionListener to a label in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, hyperlink, label

i'm trying to add an ActionListener to a label whitch pop out whenever user types wrong password or login.
Here is my Login Controller

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private TextField LoginField;
@FXML
private PasswordField PasswdField;
@FXML
private Button LogInButton;
@FXML
private Label IncorrectDataLabel;
//private String uri = "http://google.com";



@FXML
private void LogIn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if(LoginField.getText().equals("MKARK")&&PasswdField.getText().equals("KACZOR1"))
    {

        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxmlFiles/MainScreen.fxml"));
        Scene MainScene = new Scene(parent);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(MainScene);
        stage.show();


    }
    else
    {
        IncorrectDataLabel.setVisible(true);
        // <------------------- Here I want to bind hyperlink to a label with would open the google site, whenever user clicks it.
}




@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

How am i able to fix that issue? I've tried many times (setOnAction, addMouseListener) but nothing worked :(.

If You dont mind i would also ask about the public void initialize function. What is it for? It pop out automatically when i created the class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Labels don't fire action events, so it's not clear what you mean. What does the user actually do that you want to cause this method to run? (The `initialize()` method is invoked after the `@FXML`-annotated fields have been injected, and is for initializing the controller.)

Comment: I mean that after this IncorrectDataLabel poped out, the user will be able to click on it and redirected to the website i want (just like the hyperlinks works).

Comment: Why not use a [`Hyperlink`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Hyperlink.html) instead of a label?

Comment: Frankly speaking, i dont know =D. I'm just trying everything up :P. I will try with that! Thanks

Comment: By the way, could you answer me one more question. I'm using SceneBuilder to build the whole layout in fxml stuff, but do people use it in everyday coding or it's just simplified method for the newbie =D. I'm wondering if it's good for me to start with such an convenience :P

Comment: Ah, that's a broad question that is really a matter of opinion. SceneBuilder is great for quick prototyping, and also pretty good for starting a complex UI. I often find there's something I need to do that's not supported by SceneBuilder, e.g. `<fx:include>` or `<fx:define>` elements, so in a medium-large scale project I might start the various UI screens with SceneBuilder but sometimes end up editing the FXML code later.  Separating the view (FXML) from the controller is a good thing in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really do appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Labels do not fire action events. You could use a listener for mouse clicked events, e.g:

```
@FXML
private void gotoGoogle() {
    // open url etc
}
```

and in the FXML file

```xml
<Label fx:id="IncorrectDataLabel" onMouseClicked="#gotoGoogle" ... />
```

However, it probably makes more sense to use a [`Hyperlink`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Hyperlink.html) for this, which would give the user better visual feedback that it was something on which they were expected to click. Just replace the label with

```xml
<Hyperlink fx:id="IncorrectDataLabel" onAction="#gotoGoogle" text="..." ... />
```

and update the type in the controller accordingly:

```
@FXML
private Hyperlink IncorrectDataLabel ;
```

You need the appropriate import for `javafx.control.Hyperlink` in both the FXML file and in the controller.

Off-topic note: use [proper Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) for your variable and method names.