# How to let users interact with text in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I want to create a JavaFX tool where users annotate entities in text, such as persons. In JavaScript this is easy, for example:

`<span onClick="openMenu('Joana')">Joana</span> eats an apple.`

I can use the HTMLEditor class in JavaFX, but how can I call Java functions from within that HTML. Is that even possible? Or is there another way to create click listeners to words in text in JavaFX?

Comment: You can add onMouseClicked event to Label, described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855779/how-to-add-a-actionlistener-to-a-label-in-javafx